# Angular 10 scrollTo from parent component to an element in child component html

Tags: html, angular, scroll, angular10

parent html:

```
 <div>
  <button type="button" (click)="scroll(childelementTwo)">TO CHILD</button>
 </div>

 <div>
  <app-child>
 </div>
```

child html:

```
 <div>
    <div #childelementOne>
      lot of stuff
    </div>

    <div #childelementTwo>
     another lot of stuff
    </div>

   </div>
```

if all this html code were in the "same" component.html I would use this function, but not:

```
  scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
 }
```

So: How can I scroll to an  html element in child component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mat, your "elements" are in child and you want control in parent. So, first make access to the elements in child using ViewChild

```
//in your child.component
@ViewChild("childelementOne") childelementOne;
@ViewChild("childelementTwo") childelementTwo;
```

Then in parent you can do

```
<div>
  <button type="button" (click)="scroll(childComponent.childelementTwo)">
       TO CHILD
   </button>
</div>

<div>
  <!--see that use a template reference variable to the childComponent-->
  <app-child #childComponent></app-child>
 </div>

 scroll(el: ElementRef) {
   el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
 }
```

See how, in the .html we are using `childComponent.childelementTwo`. `childComponent`is the own component app-child, `childComponent.childelementTwo` is the "variable" that we get in the `@ViewChild`. By defect is an ElementRef. You get to the HTMLElement using el.nativeElement. Yes, using a template reference we can access to all the public variables and public function of your child.component

I create [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bedcu3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that is looks like the stackblitz in enno's answer, but see that is complety different

NOTE. You can also use the same referenceVariable in the child.component and use ViewChildren, so you can pass to the function the QueryList and the index

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@ViewChildren` for this.

List-Item:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-item',
  templateUrl: './list-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-item.component.css']
})
export class ListItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() list;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  scrollIntoView() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }

}
```

List-Component:

```
  @ViewChildren(ListItemComponent) viewChildren!: QueryList<ListItemComponent>;
  list = new Array(1000).fill(true)

  scrollTo() {
    this.viewChildren.toArray()[100].scrollIntoView()
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button (click)="scrollTo()">scroll to 100</button>
<app-list-item *ngFor="let item of list">
list works!
</app-list-item>
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ccaav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: No, I am not using ngfor, div in child element contains different content

Comment: If scrollIntoView still does not work, try wrapping it in setTimeout.
`setTimeout(_ => whatever.nativeElement.scrollIntoView())`